# curl and php html not logging in correcty i know curl functions work

Tags: php, html, curl, authentication

I know my curl script works correctly. I can hardcode the email and pass in curl and it works fine, but now I am trying to create a php script to input it and it doesn't work. I will post links and code below. 
I am using the input email@ccc.com:passss.

> http://cyber-hosted.com/CH/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="n.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="mail />
<input type="password" name="pass" />
</form>
</body>
```

> http://cyber-hosted.com/CH/n.php

```
<?php
$usermail = $_POST['Mail'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];



$url = "https://secure.tesco.com/register/default.aspx?vstore=0";
//
$h = curl_init();
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "form=fSignin&from=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.tesco.com%2Fclubcard%2Fmyaccount%2Fhome.aspx&formData=bmV3UmVnPWZhbHNlJg%3D%3D&loginID=$usermail&password=$pass&seamlesswebtag=&confirm-signin.x=47&confirm-signin.y=18");
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//
$result = curl_exec($h);
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You typed mail with uppercase:

```
$usermail = $_POST['Mail'];
//        here -----^
```

Change it to:

```
$usermail = $_POST['mail'];
```

Ah and I almost forgot the double quotes here:

```
<input type="text" name="mail />
<!--            here --------^    --->
```

It should be `<input type="text" name="mail" />`

Comment: There are 2 errors on this page.

    â€œEmail addressâ€ is a required item. You must supply a value
    â€œPasswordâ€ is a required item. You must supply a value

Comment: @DavidTuckwell Then there is something else that is triggering the error, I can't know the error without the full code of `n.php`

Comment: i fixed error on php also as i forgot and  got a new box on my html for password but i cannt press enter and submint like befor now i get no results from tesco site it does not submit

Comment: Add a button `<input type="submit" value="send"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the fields a value attribute

```
<input type="text" name="mail" value=""/>
<input type="password" name="pass" value=""/>
```

Also you are missing the submit button from your supplied code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

And finally you should URL encode the usermail and password parameters in the cURL request.